# How to create instances of subclasses based on the value of a super class attribute

Tags: inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a super class Person with a private attribute age, I want to have subclasses Baby, Adult, Old and instances of these classes are created based on the age of the Person..How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a class factory that creates the correct instances based on the age.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_class